# How to calculate the pH of a 0.325 M solution of pyridine hydrofloride?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

How to calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a $0.325~\mathrm{M}$ solution of $\ce{C5H5NHF}$? The $K_\mathrm{b}$ for $\ce{C5H5N}$ and $\ce{C5H5NH+}$ is $1.7\times 10^{-9}$.

Here's my work, but it's wrong (at least I tried):

$$\ce{C5H5NHF -> C5H5NH+ + F- }$$
$$K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{HF})= 4.0\cdot10^{-4}$$
$$K=\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}}$$
$$K=\frac{1\cdot10^{-14}}{4.0\cdot10^{-4}}=2.5\cdot10^{-11}$$

Construct an ice table:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
&\ce{F-}&\ce{+H2O(l)->}&\ce{HF}&+\ce{OH-}\\\hline
\text{I}&\pu{0.325M}&&0&0 \\\hline
\text{C}&-x&&x&x\\\hline
\text{E}&\pu{0.325M}-x&&x&x\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Set up the equation (small x-approximation):
$$2.5\cdot10^{-11} = \frac{x^2}{0.325-x}$$
Now, cross multiply:
$$x^2 = 5.87\cdot10^{-12}$$
Take the square root of both sides:
$$[\ce{OH-}] = x = 2.42\cdot10^{-6}$$
You want to get from $[\ce{OH-}]$ to $\mathrm{pOH}$:
$$\mathrm{pOH} = -\log\left(2.42\cdot10^{-6}\right) = 5.616$$
Then, from $\mathrm{pOH}$ to $\mathrm{pH}$:
$$\mathrm{pH} = 14 - 5.616 = 8.384$$ 
Which is the wrong answer.

What am I doing wrong? How do I even use the $K_\mathrm{b}$ value in my calculation?

Comment: You didn't take into account the ionization of $\ce{C5H5NH^{+}}$ anywhere. That equilibrium will affect the final pH. You have a problem asking about the pH of a salt solution made of both a weak acid and a weak base. This will make it trickier than usual.

Comment: So, my K equation should actually look like 1/Ka * 1/Kb * Kw to take in the account of the Kb value?

Comment: The fact that the pyridinium cation $\ce{C5H5NH+}$ is more acidic (pKa = 5.25) than $\ce{F-}$ is basic (pKb = 10.83) somewhat supports this idea that the dissociation of $\ce{F-}$ is supposed to be ignored. Although I definitely think that the question should have given a non-basic anion such as $\ce{Cl-}$ in this case.

Comment: The intro of this old ACS [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed016p140#/doi/abs/10.1021/ed016p140) might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the issue is that you are looking at the wrong reaction. I believe the reaction should be $$\ce{C5H5NHF_{(s)} ->C5H5NH+_{(aq)} + F-_{(aq)}->C5H5N_{(aq)} + HF_{(aq)}}$$ When looking at this, we can start by noting that $\ce{HF}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{C5H5NH+}$, so the reaction will favor the reactants. Then, we can compare the reactants and note that $\ce{C5H5NH+}$ has a greater acid strength than the base strength of $\ce{F-}$  (ie $\mathrm{K_a} $ of $\ce{C5H5NH+} >\mathrm{K_b} \text{ of } \ce{F-} $) so the solution will be acidic. Its always useful to have this sort of sanity to check to make sure your answer makes sense. (For more details on this portion, [Cengage](http://www.cengage.com/chemistry/discipline_content/owl/support/chapters/owlbook_ch17.pdf) has a chapter discussing acid/base mixtures)

A good approximation for the pH can be found in this [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed016p140#/doi/abs/10.1021/ed016p140), as shown here: $$[\ce{H3O+}]=\mathrm{K_a}*\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{K_w}}{\mathrm{K_a * K_b}}}$$ where $\mathrm{K_a}$ is for $\ce{C5H5NH+}$ and $\mathrm{K_b}$ is for 
$\ce{F-}$. This leads to $[\ce{H3O+}]=4.85*10^{-5}\to\mathrm{pK_a}=4.314$

As a comparison, the $\text{p}\ce{H}$ of $.325$M pyridinium is $2.86$, which it makes sense that the $\text{p}\ce{H}$ is higher when it is mixed with a base.